# What is the difference between Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resourcemanager.Fluent and Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent nuget packages?

Tags: azure, nuget-package, azure-management-api

There are 2 nuget packages for Azure resource management:

1. [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resourcemanager.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent)
2. [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent)

How exactly are these nuget packages differ and when to use which one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent) is a [wrapper package](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net#latest-stable-release), it depends on other dedicated packages like `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resourcemanager.Fluent` / `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent` etc. You can refer to this screenshot below:

[image]

The [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent) package provides basic functions like authentication / specify subscription etc. And it also provides a lot of properties like `ResourceGroups` / `StorageAccounts`, you can use these properties to create entry point to `ResourceGroups` / `StorageAccounts` management. Here is a screenshot as below:

[image]

The package `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resourcemanager.Fluent` is used to manage azure resources like create / update / delete a resource group / storage account etc. It needs the package `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` for authentication / get a entry point.

So for your question, you should always install the package [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent), which would automatically install all the other dedicated packages I listed in screenshot 1. Then in your code, [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent) provides some basic services like authentication / create entry point, the other packages like `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Resourcemanager.Fluent` is then used to do some management thing a for azure resource like create / update / delete.

For better understanding, you can go through the samples [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/Samples/AppService/ManageWebAppLogs.cs).